# Single Sign-on via Apache2 on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.4, kerberos

I have installed and already set Single Sign-on on Ubuntu server... on Apache2

But now have change domain from PREVIOUS.COM to NEW.COM

I have already created on on domain krb5.keytab and placed to Ubuntu
Where I was already updated krb5.conf for new domain

And finnally updated sites in Apache2.

Now I see error HTTP 500 on Apache and in log is posible to see

```
[auth_kerb:error] [pid 2421] [client 10.200.147.133:63820] gss_accept_sec_context() failed: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (,
 Cannot find key for HTTP/new_user@NEW.COM kvno 1 in keytab (request ticket server HTTP/previous_user@PREVIOUS.COM))
```

Soo... Apache2 already send request for new domain. But somewhere is configured old domain and old domain user.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "new_user" and "previous_user"? Do the log files show AD usernames instead of domain names? How exactly did you update sites in Apache2?

Comment: Was it the website domain that changed, or the Kerberos realm, or both?